# bubblesort vector line by line. integer C#

Tags: c#

This is one of my else statement that should display highscore leader in console. The data comes from my textfile that contain interger string. But my bubblesort doesn't seems to display anything in console. It just iterates back to meny directly. Could you perhaps find out if its something that I might have missed?

```
else if (menu == 2)
{
    string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\Highscore.txt");
    string temp;
    string scoret;

    for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < allLines.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            allLines[i] = string.Copy(allLines[j]);
            if (allLines[i].CompareTo(allLines[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                temp = allLines[j];
                allLines[j] = allLines[i];
                allLines[i] = Convert.ToString(temp);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(allLines[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(allLines[allLines.Length - 1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Anyone who could advice me of what I've missing?

Comment: Why not simply use `Array.Sort` ? I wouldn't even bother with implementing bubblesort.

Comment: I agree Is this an exercise where you've been asked to code bubble sort?

Comment: Console.ReadLine(); will wait for an input

Comment: Why this line: 

   allLines[i] = string.Copy(allLines[j]);

Comment: Basically because my text file which array comes from, is not sorted at all. The text file contain an integer(score) followed by string(name). My program should sort each line and place them in right line

Comment: @JayMee well the sorting wont be completed at this point so you will have to keep hitting enter to get to the end

Comment: You program is basically stuck at: Console.ReadLine(); you have two for loops your first one is stuck waiting for input!!

Comment: Yes. But why are you replacing allLines[i] with index j, prior to your compare check? 

Also: 

allLines[i].CompareTo(allLines[j + 1]) > 0, why j+1?

Comment: I am assuming you have all lines in this vector in unordered form... 

As for being stuck on ReadLine, if you press enter a lot of times, it should eventually go through right, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops look strange, like i noted in my comments to your post (regarding how you index).

I did this in LinqPad 4, which i think is what you want?

```
void Main()
{
string[] allLines = {"Test", "Apple", "FishBowl", "Candy Cane", "Martini", "Husky"};



for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < allLines.Length; j++)
    {
       // allLines[i] = string.Copy(allLines[j]);
        if (allLines[i].CompareTo(allLines[j]) > 0)
        {
            string temp = allLines[i];
            allLines[i] = allLines[j];
            allLines[j] = temp;
        }

    }


}
Console.WriteLine(allLines);
}
```

Note the altered loops and indexing.

Also, remove the ReadLine statement

Comment: That's correct, the lines in the textfile is not sorted. Each line contain 1 players score.

It's very strange, because the WriteLine reads allLines as string[2]. However, console output is System,String[].

No matter if I use your code. Output is still System.String[]

I solved it now.......

But as I thought, ít just compare first type, so if a player score 11 points, 
the player is highest up in highscore but should be lowest.